# Validate decimal number

Tags: java, csv, decimalformat

I'm reading some .csv file that contain string that rapresents decimal number. My trouble is that many times I'm reciving file write with different locale. For example:

1. The value of the column price of file1.csv is 129,13 (, is a decimal separator)
2. The value of the column price of file1.csv is 129.13 (. is a decimal separator)

Now I'm trying to read the value in this way:

```
 DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = new DecimalFormatSymbols(new Locale(en,US));
 DecimalFormat df= new DecimalFormat();
 df.setDecimalFormatSymbols(dfs);
 df.setParseBigDecimal(true);
 bigDecimal = (BigDecimal) df.parse(value);
```

Using this snippet code the first value become 12913 (not correct), while the second one become 129.13 (correct). Now I would want that if I using en_US local and the file contains values that use , like decimal separator, I have to throw an exception.

How can I do this?

Comment: You could try and check the value first using a dynamically built regex using `dfs.getDecimalSeparator()`, which for English might result in an expression like `\d+(\.\d{1,2})?` which would allow for integer and decimal values using the dot as the decimal separator and allowing for 1 to 2 fraction digits.

Comment: That's a bit strange, that you don't have a uniform way of formatting these numbers. What is the delimiter of the CSV file?

Comment: @Tom I don't know the delimeter separator, because my system interacts with an external system that can generate the file in both way.

Comment: Then how should you be able to know it the `,` is a delimiter between columns or a symbol for the number?

Answer (score 0):

While you cannot set nothing (null) for the group separator (as it is a `char`) when using the `DecimalFormatSymbols` you can set it to something very unusual to be found in a valid number, such as '@'.

```
 DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = new DecimalFormatSymbols(new Locale(en,US));
 dfs.setGroupingSeparator('@');
 DecimalFormat df= new DecimalFormat();
 df.setDecimalFormatSymbols(dfs);
 df.setParseBigDecimal(true);
 bigDecimal = (BigDecimal) df.parse(value);
```

Comment: What happens if you don't supply the `Locale` to the `DecimalFormatSymbols` constructor e.g. DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = new DecimalFormatSymbols();

Comment: It takes default local, but the result don't change

Answer (score 0):

From the [Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html):

```
DecimalFormatSymbols unusualSymbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols(currentLocale);
unusualSymbols.setDecimalSeparator('|');
unusualSymbols.setGroupingSeparator('^');

String strange = "#,##0.###";
DecimalFormat weirdFormatter = new DecimalFormat(strange, unusualSymbols);
weirdFormatter.setGroupingSize(4);
```

You need to set the DeciamlFormat pattern to pull it all together.

```
DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = new DecimalFormatSymbols(new Locale(en,US));
dfs.setGroupingSeparator('@');

DecimalFormat df= new DecimalFormat(#,###.#", dfs);
df.setParseBigDecimal(true);

bigDecimal = (BigDecimal) df.parse(value);
```

Comment: **129,13** become **129**

Comment: I guess there is no "beautiful" solution for this problem. OP gets an CSV file with an unknown delimiter and `","` or `"."` as the decimal separator. He could do something like `string.replace(",", ".");`, but this is far from "optimal". The best solution would be, if OP has an info which sign has which meaning in the current file, or if he could get these file in a uniform structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can read your CSVs with [univocity-parsers](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial).

We are still working on version 2.0, which introduces format auto-detection, but you can already get a snapshot version and use it to handle this.

Simple example:

```
public static void main(String... args) {

    CsvParserSettings parserSettings = new CsvParserSettings();
    parserSettings.detectFormatAutomatically();

    List<String[]> rows = new CsvParser(parserSettings).parseAll(new StringReader("Amount,Tax,Total\n1.99,10.0,2.189\n5,20.0,6"));
    for (Object[] row : rows) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
    }

    System.out.println("####");

    rows = new CsvParser(parserSettings).parseAll(new StringReader("Amount;Tax;Total\n1,99;10,0;2,189\n5;20,0;6"));
    for (Object[] row : rows) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[Amount, Tax, Total]
[1.99, 10.0, 2.189]
[5, 20.0, 6]
####
[Amount, Tax, Total]
[1,99, 10,0, 2,189]
[5, 20,0, 6]
```

You can get the latest snapshot version from [here](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/univocity/univocity-parsers/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/).

Or, if you use maven, add this to your **pom.xml**:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>ossrh</id>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

And set the version to 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.univocity</groupId>
        <artifactId>univocity-parsers</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

If you find any problem, just open a new issue [in the project's github page](https://github.com/uniVocity/univocity-parsers/issues/new)

Edit: another example demonstrating how you can convert your input rows to BigDecimal, using multiple formatters:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    // ObjectRowListProcessor converts the parsed values and stores the result in a list.
    ObjectRowListProcessor rowProcessor = new ObjectRowListProcessor();

    FormattedBigDecimalConversion conversion = new FormattedBigDecimalConversion();
    conversion.addFormat("0.00", "decimalSeparator=.");
    conversion.addFormat("0,00", "decimalSeparator=,");

    // Here we convert fields at columns 0, 1 and 2 to BigDecimal, using two possible input formats 
    rowProcessor.convertIndexes(conversion).set(0, 1, 2);

    // Create a settings object to configure the CSV parser
    CsvParserSettings parserSettings = new CsvParserSettings();

    //I'll separate the values using | to make it easier for you to identify the values in the input
    parserSettings.getFormat().setDelimiter('|');

    // We want to use the RowProcessor configured above to parse our data 
    parserSettings.setRowProcessor(rowProcessor);


    // Create the parser
    CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(parserSettings);

    // Parse everything. All rows are sent to the rowProcessor configured above
    parser.parse(new StringReader("1.99|10.0|2.189\n1,99|10,0|2,189"));

    // Let's get the parsed rows
    List<Object[]> rows = rowProcessor.getRows();
    for (Object[] row : rows) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
    }
}
```

And here's the output: 2 arrays with BigDecimal objects, and the correct values:

```
[1.99, 10.0, 2.189]
[1.99, 10.0, 2.189]
```

Comment: Can that parser handle the situation, where no "header" is present in the CSV, so the `,` or the `.` of the number is the first possible delimiter it can "reach"?

Comment: Yes, no problem with that. By default it does not read headers anyway. I added them to my example to make it easier to read.

Comment: Then how does it decide which character is the delimiter?

Comment: It analyzes a portion of the input before starting the parsing process. Basically it collects statistics with occurrences of candidate characters in a few input rows. If the same character occurs in all (valid) rows, with little variance (for example, always 10-11 commas in every row), then it is chosen as the separator. It also detects the line separator, quotes and quote escapes. Give it a try!