# Why does a German localised DecimalFormat successfully parse "3.2" as a decimal in Java?

Tags: java, format, locale, decimalformat

I would expect that

```
var decimal = DecimalFormat.getInstance(locale).parse(number);
```

yields a ParseException when the locale is de_DE and the number is "3.2" as "." is not a valid separater for this Locale.
Why is this? Wasn't the idea of a Locale that all these formatting questions are handled in a standardised way?

Comment: For the locale `de_DE` the `.` is the grouping separator and during parsing `DecimalFormat` ignores grouping separators.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## FULL STOP effectively has no meaning in German numeric parsing

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70383872/why-does-a-german-localised-decimalformat-successfully-parse-3-2-as-a-decimal/70387716#comment124418076_70383872), the [FULL STOP](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2e/index.htm) (`.`) character in German is a [thousands grouping mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator#Digit_grouping) (not a [decimal separator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator)). Its use is *not* semantic, it has no meaning. `DecimalFormat` does not enforce any rules about grouping a certain number of digits.

So in your code **the dot is effectively ignored**. The `3` and the `2` are considered as if they are `32`, and therefore parsed as thirty-two.

Example code.

```java
//Locale locale = Locale.US ;      // Parses FULL STOP as a decimal separator, with 3.2 as result. 
Locale locale = Locale.GERMANY ;   // Parses FULL STOP as a digit grouping, with 32 as result.
String input = "3.2" ;
var decimal = DecimalFormat.getInstance( locale ).parse( input );
System.out.println( decimal ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/YMArFw).

> 32

Comment: Thanks Basil! As you said 3.2 is not a valid decimal number using the German locale. How can I test whether a string is a valid decimal, if the DecimalFormat doesn't inform me? Is there any other possibility?

Comment: @Gregor https://stackoverflow.com/q/30868047/642706

Answer (score 0):

It will successfully parse it even with a different character instead of `.`.
See the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/text/NumberFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String)) of `NumberFormat.parse`:

> Parses text from the beginning of the given string to produce a number. **The method may not use the entire text of the given string.**

As long as the input starts with `3` the `parse` method will always succeed for your locale. (Are there locales that don't understand Arabic digits even?)